# How to properly set dynamic route in Next.js when basePath is not root?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I've followed this [tutorial](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/deploy-your-nextjs-application-on-a-different-base-path-i-e-not-root-1c4d210cce8a) to set up my Next.js project to reside outside of the website root. (I placed it in /app subfolder).

It all worked fine until I started to use dynamic routes for a couple of pages.

I tried in three ways:

1. `<Link href="/project/[project_id]" as="/app/project/project1">`

Which returns error `Error: The provided 'as' value (/app/project/project1) is incompatible with the 'href' value (/project/[project_id])`

2. `<Link href="/project/project1" as="/app/project/project1">`

which kind of works (it navigates) but it fails to preload next pages (I get errors 404 - not found for pages linked like this)

3. `<Link href="/app/project/project1" as="/app/project/project1">`

Does not work at all.

Anyone has an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Hey. same issue here. could you find any solution for it?

Comment: Not really, I've kind of gave up at one point and set up the project in root. Couldn't really find an easy elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Setup a [basePath](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/basepath) in your next.config

```
basePath: '/app'
```

Now, remove any reference to `/app` from your Link components.

```
<Link href="/project/[project_id]" as="/project/project1">
```

This is correct and working since next 9.5 for us